# App not installed for this user

Tags: android, adb, uninstallation

I see App in my Apps section of settings which says `App not installed for this user`. It's completely greyed out and I cannot uninstall it. When I install the same from [play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.osfg.ringtonesetter.main) it says incompatible version is already installed.

I just want to remove this App from my device.

[image]
[image]

Doesn't get uninstalled from adb either

> C:\Users\athakur>adb uninstall com.osfg.rintonesetter.main
>   Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

and

> C:\Users\athakur>adb shell pm uninstall -k com.osfg.rintonesetter.main
>   Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: It's possibly a customized ROM feature. You can't touch it if your device isn't rooted.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall that app with Clean Master?

Comment: You can see one hamburg type of icon for pop up in app info screen.When you will click on it it will show you to uninstall for all users.Just do that.After that you can again install this app from play store.In lollipop version this functionality added.

Comment: @JayShah - great answer, thanks! You should add that as the answer as it's what worked for me.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Top right menu button "uninstall for all users"

Comment: For me this happened because of an upgrade from 5 to 6.0.

Comment: Good find, but any other suggestions? This and adb uninstall aren't working. Phone claims the pkg is still present, and won't let the pkg be reinstalled with a different signing key.

Answer (score 9):

Guest user is using this App.Open that App Info, click the three vertical dots and Click Uninstall for All Users.

Or simple remove Guest user by opening guest user account.